# delayed_job pid file location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

Does anyone know how to configure delayed_jobs to place the pid file in another folder?  I see the pid_dir as an option, but not sure how to include the option in an initializer or within the script/delayed_job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, it isn't pretty, but this is one solution.  I modified the delayed_job script so that no matter how it is called (command line, capistrano, etc) it will always use the pid location I specify.

This line just adds the argument to the script:

```
ARGV << "--pid-dir=#{RAILS_ROOT}/pids"
```

For context, this is the entire modified script/delayed_job file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))
require 'delayed/command'

# Will always specify the pid directory
ARGV << "--pid-dir=#{RAILS_ROOT}/pids"

Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize
```

Comment: Should be Rails.root instead RAILS_ROOT

Comment: In case you are using Capistrano, a cleaner way to do it is to just add the "--pid-dir=#{shared_path}/pids" to the ```delayed_job_args``` variable in Capistrano as follows: ```set :delayed_job_args, "-n 2 --pid-dir=#{shared_path}/pids"```